# Incorrect cursor position in formatted JTextField input when inserting grouping characters

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a simple class based on `JFormattedTextField` which is supposed to only allow numeric input (including floating point numbers).
I am using a DecimalFormatter to achieve the input validation as this is apparently the go-to way of doing this in Swing according to the research that I did.
While the class does restrict input properly and as expected, whenever the user types a digit that will cause a grouping seperator to be added (eg going from `123` to `1,234` the cursor will move incorrectly one position to the left (ex: `1,23|4` while it should be `1,234|`). This makes inputting numbers very problematic for the user.

How can I make the cursor stay at the correct position when grouping seperators are added?

Minimal code example:

```
public class JFloatTextField extends JFormattedTextField {

public JFloatTextField() {
    this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {
        @Override
        public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
            DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
            format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
            format.setGroupingUsed(true);
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
            InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
            formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
            formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
            formatter.setMaximum(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            return formatter;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.